# get the common rows from two tables with un-common one column in ms sql 2005

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables named SAP & PRO. They have same columns in them that are - Part, Description & Quantity. Here are some sample data

```
create table SAP(
    Part char(1),
    Description varchar(20),
    Qty int
)
create table PRO(
    Part char(1),
    Description varchar(20),
    Qty int
)
insert into SAP values
('A', 'Apple', 2),
('A', 'Apple', 4),
('B', 'Ball', 3),
('C', 'Card', 1),
('C', 'Card', 4),
('D', 'Doll', 5),
('E', 'Egg', 12),
('F', 'Fish', 23),
('G', 'Gun', 50);

insert into PRO values
('A', 'Apple', 6),
('B', 'Ball', 1),
('D', 'Doll', 4),
('E', 'Egg', 20),
('F', 'Fish', 10);
```

**SAP**

```
Part Description          Qty
---- -------------------- -----------
A    Apple                2
A    Apple                4
B    Ball                 3
C    Card                 1
C    Card                 4
D    Doll                 5
E    Egg                  12
F    Fish                 23
G    Gun                  50
```

**PRO**

```
Part Description          Qty
---- -------------------- -----------
A    Apple                6
B    Ball                 1
D    Doll                 4
E    Egg                  20
F    Fish                 10
```

As seen, both have few records common in them

I want to get the common records in them with Part and Description along with the quantity in both the tables. Common records are Part - A, B, D, E, F, description - Apple, Ball, Doll, Egg, Fish and quantity in table SAP - 2, 4 for Apple, 3 for Ball, 5 for Doll, 12 for Egg, 23 for Fish and quantity in PRO table - 6 for Apple, 1 for Ball, 4 for Doll, 20 for Egg, 10 for Fish (as shown in the figure below: )

```
Part    Description     Qty in SAP  Qty in PRO
---- ------------------ ----------  ----------
A       Apple           2           6
A       Apple           4           6
B       Ball            3           1
D       Doll            5           4
E       Egg             12          20
F       Fish            23          10
```

Comment: I've updated your question and added a readily consumable data. Also do not post images as this will not help us.

Comment: oh, ok, sorry, did not know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Part and Description are identical, you can do this with joins, does something like like this do it?

```
    SELECT
    S.part,
    S.description,
    S.quantity, 
    P.quantity
FROM SAP S
INNER JOIN PRO P
    ON S.Part = p.Part
    AND S.Description = P.Description
```

You can change the join to LEFT or RIGHT as needed to see the unique records too. As a separate note, it is a bad idea to have duplicate key values in the same table (Apple for instance), I would recommend de-duping this and adding a unique index to prevent dupes from re-appearing.

Comment: hi, it does not remove duplicate

Comment: It's not supposed to remove the dupes, merely identify them as per your question. You could use GROUP BY and INSERT INTO to remove the dupes and insert the unique records into a new table.

Answer (score 0):

The following Query should help you to get the desired output:

```
`SELECT SAP.Part, SAP.[Description], SAP.Qty AS [Qty in SAP], PRO.Qty AS [Qty in PRO] FROM [SAP] INNER JOIN [dbo].[PRO] ON SAP.Part=PRO.Part AND SAP.[Description]=PRO.[Description]`
```

Comment: hi, it does not remove duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Try this

SELECT

```
    SAP.Part, 
    SAP.[Description], 
    SAP.Qty as [Qty in SAP], 
    PRO.Qty as [Qty in PRO] 
FROM 
    SAP 
        INNER JOIN PRO 
            ON SAP.Part = PRO.Part AND SAP.[Description] = PRO.[Description]
```

Thanks

M. Prabhu

Comment: hi,  it does not remove duplicates